# Sass syntax for writing out this value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm just adopting Sass in a recent project and am trying to get the following code to work for rounded corners which isn't working. How would I specify this so that each rounded corner is set to 8px?

```
$radius_size:8px;
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: #{$radius_size}px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: #{$radius_size}px;
  border-top-left-radius: #{$radius_size}px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: #{$radius_size}px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: #{$radius_size}px;
  border-top-right-radius: #{$radius_size}px;
}
```

thx

Comment: Consider using Compass + SASS - with the scss border-radius mixin you'd just use @include border-radius(8px); and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just overcomplicating it!

```
$radius_size: 8px;
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: $radius_size;
  //... and so on ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like you inserting double 'px' parts.
2. You can use variables without `#{}`

   `$radius_size: 8px;`

`.rounded-corners {`

```
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: $radius_size;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: $radius_size;
    border-top-left-radius: $radius_size;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: $radius_size;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: $radius_size;
    border-top-right-radius: $radius_size;
}
```

Also, check [this site](http://sass-lang.com/try.html) for testing sass online